# Extract different kinds of protocol from URL

Tags: bash, glob

I have the following URLs with different types of protocol:

```
URL=https://example.com
URL=ftp://example.com
URL=ssh://example.com
URL=///filestore/storage
```

I'm using `echo ${URL%://*}` to get protocol, but for `///` it doesn't work, can't apply multiple regex, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this extended glob matching:

```
"${url%?(:)//*}"
```

Where `?(:)` matches an optional `:` using *extended globbing* followed by `//` and that is followed by any number of characters as per glob matching in shell.

**Code:**

```sh
for url in 'https://example.com' 'ftp://example.com' 'ssh://example.com' '///filestore/storage'; do
   echo "${url%?(:)//*}"
done

https
ftp
ssh
/
```

PS: On BASH versions < 4 use `shopt -s extglob` before this code.

Comment: but for `///filestore/storage` it not extracting `/`

Comment: with extension yes